# Выборка элемента с определённым значением атрибута

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на странице есть ряд элементов с атрибутом `name = "ShortCalcCostExplanation"` и у каждого есть атрибут `value` со значением от `0` до `n`.

Как мне, с помощью jquery, отобрать элемент, значение атрибута `value` которого будет равно значению из переменной?

Получилось обойти с помощью `each`, но, вероятно, есть более правильный способ.

```
var productNumber = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-linked-radio-button");
$("[name=ShortCalcCostExplanation]").each(function(i, element) {
    if ($(element).attr("value") === productNumber) {
        //todo
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучите селекторы CSS, в частности [`селекторы по атрибуту`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Выбрать все элементы с name= ShortCalcCostExplanation и value=3 можно используя одни лишь селекторы:

```
// Нативный способ без jQuery
document.querySelectorAll('[name="ShortCalcCostExplanation"][value="3"]')

// Тоже самое, но с jQuery
$('[name="ShortCalcCostExplanation"][value="3"]')
```

Comment: поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="ShortCalcCostExplanation"][value="3"]');
```